# JSF 2 composite component + clientBehavior

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, composite-component

I have a composite component that is a specialization of PrimeFaces autoComplete.

In some pages I need to use the itemSelect event, so I added

```
<cc:clientBehavior name="itemSelect" event="itemSelect"
                   targets="#{cc.attrs.id}" />
```

in the component interface, but the action is not fired.

What am I missing?

**Component code:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" >    

    <!-- INTERFACE -->
    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="value" required="true" />
        <cc:attribute name="disabled" default="false" />
        <cc:attribute name="required" default="false" />
        <cc:attribute name="size" default="25" />
        <cc:clientBehavior name="itemSelect" event="itemSelect"
            targets="#{cc.attrs.id}" />
    </cc:interface>

    <!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
    <cc:implementation>
        <p:autoComplete disabled="#{cc.attrs.disabled}"
            value="#{cc.attrs.value}"
            completeMethod="#{tecnicoBean.completarViajante}" var="t"
            itemLabel="#{t.nome}" itemValue="#{t}" minQueryLength="2"
            forceSelection="true" converter="entityConverter"
            size="#{cc.attrs.size}" queryDelay="700" label="Técnico:"
            onclick="this.select()" cache="true">
        </p:autoComplete>
    </cc:implementation>
</html>
```

Component usage:

```
<ezcomp:tecnicos value="#{sessionScope.tecnicoRdv}">
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" process="@this" update=":mainPanel"
            listener="#{rdvBean.changeTecnico}" />
</ezcomp:tecnicos>
```

Comment: Please format your `code indentation` before posting your code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working.

I had to add `id="#{cc.attrs.id}"` to the *p:autoComplete* component.

Answer (score 1):

cc:clientBehavior targets - list of local id's. Correct way to use unique id for p:autoComplete

```
<p:autoComplete id="someUniqueId" ... />
```

and link it to cc:clientBehavior

```
<cc:clientBehavior name="itemSelect" event="itemSelect"
            targets="someUniqueId" />
```